# patch a git branch from another branch

Tags: git, github

i need to arrive at HEAD of branch B on top of branch A in a single commit. 
The last commit of branch B is a result of `git merge A` so now it is `Already up-to-date.` as it should.

Now i try:

```
git checkout B
git format-patch A --stdout > AB.patch
git checkout A
git apply AB.patch
```

but it gives a million errors with `patch does not apply`

I also tried:

```
git checkout A
git diff A B > AB.patch
git apply AB.patch
```

which fails on `cannot apply binary patch to` errors.

What is the solution and why do the above fail?
Thanks

Comment: Before I post an answer, I need to clarify some things. You are on `branch B` and you want to create a patch of `branch B` compared to `branch A`? You said, the last commit of `branch B` is a merge of `A` so this means, `A` and `B` are even. You see, there is some clarification work to do you to get a feasible answer.

Comment: of course A and B are not even, A is merged into B, so commits of A is a subset of commits of B, I simply want to now apply the changes in a single commit to submit a PR from B against A that has one commit. It is basically a rebase of B on A but i want to arrive at a one-commit PR via a patch

Comment: Well regarding to your code you posted you have `git branch B` in it, this will basically not do what you have intended to do. You may want to do `git checkout B` and then to do the `git format-patch`

Comment: sry mistake, of course it should read checkout, updated my question. thx